# Regular expression matching html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to achieve is a highlight function, where a search engine returns the right piece of HTML and the right bit of text is highlighted. So far it works. But in this text are also HTML-tags included, so if someone does a search on the letters "li" of "l" for example, the highlight function (which put a span around the word being found), breaks the tags, in this case the li tag. Because it would place a span tag around the l or i.
This, of course messes up the whole page. So,
I made a regular expression that would match all HTML-tags, and it does it!

```
/<[^<]*>/
```

As only the search item should match and NOT the HTMLtag, I made it like this,

```
/((?!<[^<]*>)/
```

This is the line in JavaScript to create the regex, where `"str"` is the string to be highlighted.

```
var regex = new RegExp("((?!<[^<]*>)("+str+"))","gi");
```

I build up the RegExp in a Regex tester, and there all is fine, but still in execution of the script, a search for `"li"` or a search that encounters a tag with the same letters, results in a page messed up.

Anyone could explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: He comes. The <center> will not hold it is too late.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1348195

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)